# How to use storm topology to implement an cache buffer with my own customised pushing&poping rules?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-storm

I have a storm topology with a spout S0 emitting tuples to a bolt B0, which is used as a buffer, and then tuples are transfered to bolt B1, which actually do calculations:

[spout S0] --tuples--> [buffer bolt B0] --tuples--> [processing bolt B1] -->...

But because the processing speed of bolt B1 is slower than the emitting speed of spout S0, I use bolt B0 as a cache buffer which holds all the incoming tuples from spout S0.

** I hope implement the bolt B0 which can receive tuples from spout S0 while emitting tuples to bolt B1, and most important of all, I hope to customise the adding and emitting strategy of the bolt B0 (which I actually used as a queue/stack etc.). **

(In my scenario, the tuples are quite small. Namely, it is fine to cache them in a single bolt B0. The bolt B0 does nothing with tuples it receive. The only reason I add such bolt B0 is that I hope to change the FIFO rule of the tuples from spout S0 to bolt B1).

This article "Understanding the Internal Message Buffers of Storm" http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/
is quite helpful to my problem. If I can change change the codes of the buffer in the worker receiver thread, I think the problem could also be solved. ** But I don't know which class in apache storm handles the buffer in/out strategy in the worker receiver thread.**

Comment: from where is your spout reading from?

Comment: I think the spout could be considered reading data from hdfs continuously. But I just hope to simplify the question, because the real situation is a bit more complex.

Comment: Actually, I connect the output stream of B1 to the input of B1 itself. The bolt B1 itself may generate more tuples after receiving one. The spout only emit one tuple to the bolt B1 once in the open() to start the process.

Comment: What I hope to implement in the bolt B0, or the internal buffer in the worker receiver thread, is to select only some of the tuples received from the spout (or the bolt B1 actually), as well as to customise my own rule to the emitting sequence of tuples from the B0 (or the internal buffer).

Comment: I have read some tutorials of compiling storm from source code. I am trying to change the strategy of sending and receiving tuples in the buffer. But I am not sure is it the class "DisruptorQueue.java" what I am looking for.

Comment: are you sure you want to process data in real time? are you sure the batch processing is not the most indicated for your use case? Because usually, Storm writes to hdfs, usually does not have a spout whom reads from HDFS.

Comment: You can refer DisruptorQueue.java and disruptor.clj. But I don't easily think about how to change the strategy. Please note that data structure of Disruptor queue is circular queue.